# matching search result with user input in JavaScript object

Tags: javascript

I want to match the object name when it is match by user input or quit if user type quit , but when I type correct name it does not show student information, I did not find any error, can somebody tell me what is wrong with my code .advance thanks.

```js
let students = [{
  Name: "golam Rabbani",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 10,
}, {
  Name: " Rabbani",
  track: "frontend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 70,
}, {
  Name: "golam",
  track: "backhend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 50,
}, {
  Name: "Rocky",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 1000,
}, {
  Name: " Rony",
  track: "IOS",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 100,
}, ];

var student;
var message = "";
var search;

function print(message) {
  let output = document.querySelector(".output");
  output.innerHTML = message;
}
while (true) {
  search = prompt("enter your name or type (quit) to leave the program");
  var leave = "quit";
  if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === leave) {
    break;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.Name === search) {
      message += "<li> student:" + student.Name + "</li>";
      message += "<p> track:" + student.track + "</p>";
      message += "<p> point:" + student.point + "</p>";
      message += "<p> Achievement:" + student.Achievement + "</p>";
      print(message);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please share your .HTML file

Comment: <ul class="output">

Comment: not working browser does not show student information while searching by name

Comment: The problem is you are invoking the prompt recursively in a loop, DOM element will update only when your script execution completed. check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/66487042/4021490

Comment: finally works with the previous code. user input is case sensitive when copy the property and past on the user input box it works fine.Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are invoking the prompt recursively in a loop, DOM element will update only when your script execution completed.

```js
let students = [{
  Name: "golam Rabbani",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 10,
}, {
  Name: " Rabbani",
  track: "frontend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 70,
}, {
  Name: "golam",
  track: "backhend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 50,
}, {
  Name: "Rocky",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 1000,
}, {
  Name: " Rony",
  track: "IOS",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 100,
}, ];

var student;
var message = "";
var search;

function print(message) {
  let output = document.querySelector(".output");
  output.innerHTML = message;
}
while (true) {
  search = prompt("enter your name or type (quit) to leave the program");
  var leave = "quit";
  if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === leave) {
    break;
  }
  let flag=false;
  
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.Name === search) {
      message += "<li> student:" + student.Name + "</li>";
      message += "<p> track:" + student.track + "</p>";
      message += "<p> point:" + student.point + "</p>";
      message += "<p> Achievement:" + student.Achievement + "</p>";
      print(message);
      flag=true;
    }
  }
  if(flag)
   break;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<body>

<ul class="output"></ul>

</body>
</head>

</html>
```

Here I have added a flag variable to break the execution when a user enters the correct name.

Answer (score 2):

You need to tidy up your code a bit:

- There are some blanks in some of your `Name` properties which makes them hard to find
- your search is case-sensitive which is also hard on the user
- you define the property `Point` but later try to find `point`
- your HTML was missing in the snippet

If your take care of the above points you script should work.

```js
let students = [{
  Name: "golam Rabbani",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 10,
}, {
  Name: " Rabbani",
  track: "frontend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 70,
}, {
  Name: "golam",
  track: "backhend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 50,
}, {
  Name: "Rocky",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 1000,
}, {
  Name: " Rony",
  track: "IOS",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 100,
}, ];

var student;
var message = "";
var search;

function print(message) {
  let output = document.querySelector(".output");
  output.innerHTML = message;
}
while (true) {
  search = prompt("enter your name or type (quit) to leave the program");
  var leave = "quit";
  if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === leave) {
    break;
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    student = students[i];
    if (student.Name === search) {
      message += "<li> student:" + student.Name + "</li>";
      message += "<p> track:" + student.track + "</p>";
      message += "<p> point:" + student.point + "</p>";
      message += "<p> Achievement:" + student.Achievement + "</p>";
      print(message);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ul class="output"></ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

because you do not pass "message" data that you get to the html tags

```
    let students = [{
      Name: "golam Rabbani",
      track: "web design",
      Achievement: "2 badge",
      Point: 10,
    }, {
      Name: " Rabbani",
      track: "frontend",
      Achievement: "2 badge",
      Point: 70,
    }, {
      Name: "golam",
      track: "backhend",
      Achievement: "2 badge",
      Point: 50,
    }, {
      Name: "Rocky",
      track: "web design",
      Achievement: "2 badge",
      Point: 1000,
    }, {
      Name: "Rony",
      track: "IOS",
      Achievement: "2 badge",
      Point: 100,
    }, ];

    var student;
    var message = "";
    var search;

    function print(message) {
      let output = document.querySelector(".output");
      output.innerHTML = message;
    }

    while (true) {
      search = prompt("enter your name or type (quit) to leave the program");
      var leave = "quit";
      if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === leave) {
        break;
      }
      else{
          for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
            student = students[i];
            if (student.Name === search) {
              message += "<li> student:" + student.Name + "</li>";
              message += "<p> track:" + student.track + "</p>";
              message += "<p> point:" + student.Point + "</p>";
              message += "<p> Achievement:" + student.Achievement + "</p>";
              print(message);
             }
          }
        }
    }
```

```js
let students = [{
          Name: "golam Rabbani",
          track: "web design",
          Achievement: "2 badge",
          Point: 10,
        }, {
          Name: " Rabbani",
          track: "frontend",
          Achievement: "2 badge",
          Point: 70,
        }, {
          Name: "golam",
          track: "backhend",
          Achievement: "2 badge",
          Point: 50,
        }, {
          Name: "Rocky",
          track: "web design",
          Achievement: "2 badge",
          Point: 1000,
        }, {
          Name: "Rony",
          track: "IOS",
          Achievement: "2 badge",
          Point: 100,
        }, ];

        var student;
        var message = "";
        var search;

        function print(message) {
          let output = document.querySelector(".output");
          output.innerHTML = message;
        }

        while (true) {
          search = prompt("enter your name or type (quit) to leave the program");
          var leave = "quit";
          if (search === null || search.toLowerCase() === leave) {
            break;
          }
          else{
              for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
                student = students[i];
                if (student.Name === search) {
                  message += "<li> student:" + student.Name + "</li>";
                  message += "<p> track:" + student.track + "</p>";
                  message += "<p> point:" + student.Point + "</p>";
                  message += "<p> Achievement:" + student.Achievement + "</p>";
                  print(message);
                 }
              }
            }
        }
```

```html
<ul class="output"><ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let students = [{
  Name: "golam Rabbani",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 10,
}, {
  Name: " Rabbani",
  track: "frontend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 70,
}, {
  Name: "golam",
  track: "backhend",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 50,
}, {
  Name: "Rocky",
  track: "web design",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 1000,
}, {
  Name: " Rony",
  track: "IOS",
  Achievement: "2 badge",
  Point: 100,
}];
var message = "";
let userInput = prompt('enter your name or type (quit) to leave the program');
if (userInput) {
  userInput = userInput.trim();
  for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    var userInputTrim = students[i].Name.trim();
    if (userInputTrim === userInput) {
      message += "<li> student:" + students[i].Name + "</li>";
      message += "<p> track:" + students[i].track + "</p>";
      message += "<p> point:" + students[i].point + "</p>";
      message += "<p> Achievement:" + students[i].Achievement + "</p>";
      print(message);
    }
  }
} else {
  alert('Please enter value!');
}

function print(message) {
  let output = document.querySelector(".output");
  output.innerHTML = message;
}
```

```html
<div class='output'></div>
```